# Setting Environment Variables using Gradle with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, environment-variables

In my Spring Boot project I have Environment Variables using a File:

[image]

When I select "Build and run using: " `Gradle`, `IntelliJ` doesn't take the environment variables value.
[image]

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand 'SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE'
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents$VarArgsTemplateVariables.getValue(UriComponents.java:370)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expandUriComponent(UriComponents.java:263)
    at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents$FullPathComponent.expand(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.expandInternal(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:440)
    at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.expandInternal(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expand(UriComponents.java:172)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.build(UriComponentsBuilder.java:517)
    at org.springframework.web.util.DefaultUriBuilderFactory.expand(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:340)
    at org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate.lambda$doRead$5(VaultTemplate.java:461)
    at org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate.doWithSession(VaultTemplate.java:448)
    at org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate.doRead(VaultTemplate.java:458)
    at org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate.read(VaultTemplate.java:353)
    at org.springframework.vault.core.lease.SecretLeaseContainer.doGetSecrets(SecretLeaseContainer.java:645)
    at org.springframework.vault.core.lease.SecretLeaseContainer.doStart(SecretLeaseContainer.java:390)
    at org.springframework.vault.core.lease.SecretLeaseContainer.start(SecretLeaseContainer.java:380)
    at org.springframework.vault.core.lease.SecretLeaseContainer.addRequestedSecret(SecretLeaseContainer.java:343)
    at org.springframework.vault.core.env.LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource.loadProperties(LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource.java:176)
    at org.springframework.vault.core.env.LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource.<init>(LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource.java:161)
    at org.springframework.vault.core.env.LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource.<init>(LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource.java:119)
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultConfigDataLoader.createLeasingPropertySource(VaultConfigDataLoader.java:287)
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultConfigDataLoader.createLeasingPropertySourceFailFast(VaultConfigDataLoader.java:310)
    ... 28 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand 'SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE'

Execution failed for task ':app:MyApplication.main()'.
> Process 'command '/usr/local/java/jdk-11.0.16.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

When I select "Build and run using: " IntelliJ IDEA runs without problem!

[image]

How to pass environment Variables value?

Comment: When running by Gradle - use Gradle means of defining environment variables. Use `applicationDefaultJvmArgs` of a Gradle `application` plugin to set environment. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html and https://stackoverflow.com/a/29464373/2000323

Comment: Thank your for providing this information. However, the solution you provided relates to environment variable expansion in JVM arguments for Gradle's `application` plugin at runtime, not build time. Am I correct here? My issue is specifically about IntelliJ IDEA recognizing environment variables during Gradle build time within the IDE, so I don't believe this solution resolves that.