# generate start script that takes environment variables with gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, open-telemetry

I am using `gradle installDist` task to prepare the data I need to then copy in the Docker image.

Now, I need to integrate openTelemetry agent, so I need to attach it on the command line. To modify the startup script, I do something like that :

```
application {
    mainClass.set("com.vincent.AppKt")
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf("-javaagent:../lib/opentelemetry-javaagent-$openTelemetryJavaAgentVersion.jar")
}
```

Next, I need to configure there a property file that is different based on the environment (staging or prod), so I need to do something like this :

```
application {
    mainClass.set("com.vincent.AppKt")
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf("-javaagent:../lib/opentelemetry-javaagent-$openTelemetryJavaAgentVersion.jar",
"-Dotel.javaagent.configuration-file=../$ENV-otel.properties")
}

tasks {
register("replaceInInstallDist") {
    dependsOn("installDist")

    doLast {
        val buildDir = file("${buildDir}/install/${project.name}")
        
        val scriptFile = file("${buildDir}/bin/${project.name}")

        scriptFile.writeText(scriptFile.readText().replace("\\\$ENV", "\$ENV"))
    }
}
}
```

(the replacement thing is inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/29464373/3067542)

it kind of works, but things are not evaluated correctly at the right time.

The generated script contains what I expect :

```
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-javaagent:../lib/opentelemetry-javaagent-2.0.0.jar" "-Dotel.javaagent.configuration-file=../$ENV-otel.properties"'
```

but once in the container, when I start the app manually, logs show that it's not evaluated :

```
ERROR io.opentelemetry.javaagent.tooling.config.ConfigurationPropertiesSupplier - Configuration file "../$ENV-otel.properties" not found.
```

If I launch myself the application from the command line, then it seems to work :

```
java -jar myJar.jar -javaagent:../lib/opentelemetry-javaagent-2.0.0.jar -Dotel.javaagent.configuration-file=../$ENV-otel.properties
```

so it seems to be an issue with how the application is launched by the generated script. it uses :

```
exec "$JAVACMD" "$@"
```

the parameters that I need to be evaluated are in the `$@` variable..

what can I do in gradle's `application` block (I guess it's there) so that my variable gets evaluated as expected, and $ENV is replaced by its value ?

Comment: Doesn’t entirely solve your problem but it’s worth noting there is https://github.com/ryandens/javaagent-gradle-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's by design since Gradle 7.2 : https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#changes_7.2

> Security changes to application start scripts and Gradle wrapper
> scripts Due to CVE-2021-32751, gradle, gradlew and start scripts
> generated by Gradle’s application plugin have been updated to avoid
> situations where these scripts could be used for arbitrary code
> execution when an attacker is able to change environment variables.
>
> You can use the latest version of Gradle to generate a gradlew script
> and use it to execute an older version of Gradle.
>
> This should be a transparent for most users; however, there may be
> changes for Gradle builds that rely on the environment variables
> JAVA_OPTS or GRADLE_OPTS to pass parameters with complicated quote
> escaping. Contact us if you suspect something has broken your build
> and you cannot find a solution.

So if we REALLY want to do it, I am not sure there's a cleaner version than the hack I did in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77909645/3067542

in my specific case for opentelemetry, I ended up using `OTEL_JAVAAGENT_CONFIGURATION_FILE` env variable instead of passing it on command line, to avoid the hack that will be a pain to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I figured a super hack-ish way of making this work, but please tell me there's  a better solution. in the `replaceInInstallDist` task, I am also adding  :

```
     scriptFile.writeText(scriptFile.readText().replace("MAX_FD=maximum", "eval \"DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=\\\"\$DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS\\\"\"\nMAX_FD=maximum"))
```

right after `DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS` is defined and the script, and before the next step that deals with `MAX_FD=maximum` , I am evaluating DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS and replacing its value.

So I am using `MAX_FD=maximum` as a token... which is going to break at some point when there's a gradle upgrade or something..